# Google map android API is not rendering in flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-2

Showing these messages after loading the map.

I/Google Maps Android API(29354): Google Play services package version: 214815038

I/Google Maps Android API(29354): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000

**Pubscpec.yaml**

**google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1**

**location: ^4.2.0**

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue.